# Beamer: tabular out of the boder

Tags: beamer, tabularx

I am writing slides under `beamer`. A tabular is out of the boder of the slides. What shoud I do? Resize?

[image]

```
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
  $\hat{\tmmathbf{v}}^1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \left(\begin{array}{c}
    1\\
    1\\
    1\\
    \vdots\\
    1
  \end{array}\right)$, & $\hat{\tmmathbf{v}}^2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}
  \left(\begin{array}{c}
    1\\
    \zeta^2\\
    \zeta^3\\
    \vdots\\
    \zeta^{N - 1}
  \end{array}\right)$, & $\hat{\tmmathbf{v}}^3 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}
  \left(\begin{array}{c}
    1\\
    \zeta^{2 \cdot 2}\\
    \zeta^{3 \cdot 2}\\
    \vdots\\
    \zeta^{( N - 1) \cdot 2}
  \end{array}\right)$,
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: You can resize, use a smaller font, or re-arrange the equations.  This is really a question of esthetics.

Comment: Use package `graphicx` and the command `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{content here}`

Answer (score 2):

### Possibility 1:

Decreasing the text size, e.g.

```
\begin{frame}[shrink=20]
...
\end{frame}
```

### Possibility 2:

Using a `plain` frame for this slide will remove the navigation bar at gives you more space

```
\begin{frame}[plain]
...
\end{frame
```

Comment: Easy and efficient way!